# Query string redirection with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On a website I'm working on now I need to set up a redirection that takes a query string into consideration.

Example:

```
http://www.domain.com/?id=86&name=John&ref=12d34 -> http://www.domain.com/?ref=12d34
http://www.domain.com/?ref=593x56&id=935 -> http://www.domain.com/?ref=593x56
http://www.domain.com/?ref=3v77l32 -> http://www.domain.com/?ref=3v77l32
```

So basically I need to find the ref parameter and it's value (whatever it's length) and append only that part to the new URL. The issue is the the ref parameter can appear anywhere within the URL.

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RewriteRule` does not work with query string directly -- you have to use `RewriteCond` for that.

Here is the rule -- it will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) ANY URL that has more than 1 parameter in query string and 1 of them is `ref`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ref=([^&]*)(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ref=([^&]*)$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}?ref=%2 [R=301,L]
```

For example:

1. It will redirect `http://www.example.com/hello.php?id=86&name=John&ref=12d34888&me=yes` to the same URL but with `ref` parameter only: `http://www.example.com/hello.php?ref=12d34888`.
2. It will do nothing if only `ref` parameter is present or no parameter at all, e.g. `http://www.example.com/hello.php?ref=12d34888` or `http://www.example.com/hello.php`.

---

If such redirect should only work for website root hits, then change the `RewriteRule` line to this:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/?ref=%2 [R=301,L]
```

(this is if placed in .htaccess file in website root folder -- if placed in server config / virtual host context the rule needs to be slightly tweaked).

`http://www.example.com/?id=86&name=John&ref=12d34888&me=yes` -> `http://www.example.com/?ref=12d34888`

---

If it has to be redirected to another domain, then replace `%{HTTP_HOST}` by domain specific name, e.g:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.exampe.com/?ref=%2 [R=301,L]
```

**It all has been tested before posting.**

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I'll comment again once I've tested it.

Comment: It works just as I needed it to. Thank you LazyOne Kenobi. You were my only hope.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ref=(.*?) /?ref=$1 [L]
```

is about as simple as it guess, but this will screw up if the `ref` query var isn't the last thing in the line - it'll slurp up everything after `ref=` and redirect that to, so

```
/blah&ref=abc&blahblahblah
```

would turn into

```
/ref=abc&blahblahblah
```

Comment: Thank you much Marc! I may indeed use this despite the caveat. Would you perhaps be able to point me in the right direction should I want to obtain the exact value instead of everything after the ref parameter?

Comment: Much obliged, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: `RewriteRule` does not work with query string parameters directly

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, what would you suggest I use instead?

Comment: @Tom See my answer. @Mark The pattern you provided is not safe, as it will also work if parameter's name has `ref` at the end, for example `myref`: `?myref=12345&id=56789` -- there is no `ref` parameter here.