# htaccess 301 Redirection based on the query string for urls

Tags: .htaccess

I've a live url some thing like this,

http://example.com/today.php?year=2012&date=24&mon=07

and i want it to redirected to

http://example.com/holiday-today/year/mon/date

I tried with %{QUERY_STRING} but i dont know how to get three query parameters and pass them to the redirected url.

How can i do this using htacess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /today\.php\?year=([0-9]+)&date=([0-9]+)&mon=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^today\.php$ /holiday-today/%1/%2/%3? [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reference these similar questions with great answers:

[Query string redirection with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000110/query-string-redirection-with-htaccess)

[301 redirect from URL with query string to new domain with different query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135702/301-redirect-from-url-with-query-string-to-new-domain-with-different-query-strin)