# How can I use htaccess to remove a URL parameter but keep a dynamic element?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Google has discovered a pager in the sidebar of a website that allows the user to scroll through 'tags' while on a blog entry, each pager click taking you to a new url, e.g. `example.com/blog/article-title?page=1`.

Since the blog has ~ 500 posts and the pager has ~ 140 pages of tags, Google has indexed a very high number of pages for my site. I don't want this for a number of reasons. I've already removed the pager on this tag block as it's completely unnecessary, but now would like to do 301 redirects on all of these `?page=X` URLs in the hopes that, over time, Google will remove them from their index.

The URLs look like this:

- http://example.com/blog/blog-article-title?page=0
- http://example.com/blog/blog-article-title?page=1
- http://example.com/blog/blog-article-title?page=2

**How can I do a 301 redirect via htaccess that will send the user to  `http://example.com/blog/blog-article-title`  ?**

I've tried many variations on

- `RewriteRule ^blog/(.*).?page(.*)$ /$1/blog/$2?
  [R=301,L]`

and

- `RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.*)\?page(.*)$ /blog/$1`

but no luck thus far. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** For others that may stumble upon this, Google had completely ignored the canonical URL that is defined in the header and indexed all 30,000+ URL combinations. Doing the htaccess rewrite in the accepted answer below is properly performing a 301 on these pages. This, of course, requires that I move the pager elsewhere, but that's already been handled in my particular situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

This should achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the `?page=` query on every single URL? On some pages the `?page=` may be necessary, i.e. a blog listing.

Comment: I updated the code to only match anything in the /blog/ directory.

Comment: That's perfect. Tried several variations on the other suggestions and just couldn't get them to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to redirect on the URL instead of the query string.  See this question: [Query string redirection with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000110/query-string-redirection-with-htaccess)

Basically, you need a `RewriteCond` based on the query string. It'll be two lines; ie:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ......
RewriteRule ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Without query_string option this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
# one url with many params
#RewriteRule ^blog/blog-article?(.*) http://www.yourblog.com/index\.php$1 [R=301,L]
# or many url
RewriteRule ^blog/sub(.*)\?(.*) http://www.yourblog.com/onething/$1?$2 [R=301,L]
```

If this doesn't work you may have some other issue in your script.